# Run feature from the step from another feature

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, gherkin

is it possible to do conditions in the feature step?

I'm running big e2e scenarios and I need to check some condition(JUnit, Maven, Java). In case if the condition is 'true' I need to run  'test2.feature', if the condition is 'false' - I need to run 'test1.feature'(or test1.feature and then test2.feature).

In my case, I need to check do I have information about person\company in the database, if yes - need to do modifications(around 150 steps), if not - need to create person\company before doing that modifications( it takes around 250 steps). I already have different e2e features that will cover both scenarios, but I do not want to run all of them in all cases.

Thank you.